# Is it possible to run 240V 30 amp service over doubled 12wg Romex line wires?

Tags: ac, mains, line

I have some existing Romex 12/2 installed on my machine. If I doubled the conductors used for each of the two line wires needed, would that adequately carry 30amps at 240 volts? This will be in open air at room temperatures.

Comment: Good luck getting it past an inspector.  The fact that it's on a machine and not in a wall might help with that, simply by an argument of jurisdiction.

Comment: Consider what happens if one wire comes off for whatever reason (cut, corroded, etc.) and the other stays there.

Comment: Information readily available via Google. Question should be closed.

Comment: It isn't in a household and won't be subject to inspection. I am wondering if it can handle it without overheating or not. As for Google - I am not sure what to sure for that is why I have asked for clarification here.

Comment: If the wire gets cut I have bigger issues - worth consideration though, thank you.

Comment: I shudder to even think of bare Romex on any kind of machinery.  Conduit and single conductors only.  This really isn't an EE question, and isn't very detailed to boot.  Vote to close.

Comment: Probably more to the point is whether your local code allows this at all, and if it is legal but non-comforming (i.e., was already present from past work) how to document or address.

Comment: 12 gauge wire can handle up to 15 amps. For 30 amps buy a larger conductor. Don't try to get by on the cheap.

Comment: @RDrast how could you say that without knowing the details of the installation? Besides, my question wasn't if Romex is acceptable to use on any type of conceivable machine.

Comment: I don't need to know the details.  For "Small Conductors", and in your case 12 AWG, whether in Romex or not is a small conductor, the MAXIMUM permissible overcurrent protection is 20A.  If you wanted to put two in parallel (still a bad idea), each feeder would need to be protected at 20 amps, so only the terminus end would actually be tied together.

Comment: @RDrast you digress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, doubled-up 12 AWG conductors will safely carry 30 Amps.

You need to adequately identify and document what is going on so that someone else down the road who works on your machine why you did what you did.

Comment: This would not be the worst code violation in history and doubling up is safer than not while you are in charge of the facility.  When you leave rip it out.  Tape or sleeve the conductor pairs together at the ends so it is obvious they are to be together (100mm or so) and most people will figure out what you did, getting it passed is likely to work in very rare locations though it was allowed in some cases in South Africa though not sure if any longer as they have approached the BS/ISO wiring code more closely.

Comment: I will use doubled 12 AWG conductors for testing and replace with 10 AWG before finishing the project.

Comment: Using multiple conductors as primary power feed conductors is common practice in larger electrical installations.  The main reason for doing so is that multiple smaller conductors are MUCH easier to pull through conduit than large conductors.